# Oracle sql constraint questions

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I'm having problems with creating a oracle sql script. How do I create these two constraints?

1. If VID is null then FID has to be null as well (VID = null -> FID = null)
2. There has to be exactly one row where VID is null which also means that FID has to be null because of 1.

Here is what I have so far:

```
create table Employee(
Id int primary key,
Name varchar(15) not null,
VID int,
FID int

);
```

[Employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Ace.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "script"? (I assume nothing - you are not using the word in the technical sense - but if I'm wrong, please explain.) Then, the first constraint is trivial to write - have you tried anything? Finally, the second condition can't be enforced with a constraint and nothing else; constraints are for conditions on individual rows, not on entire tables. One solution may be a trigger as Gordon said; another one is to create a materialized view with fast refresh on commit, which simply stores the count of nulls in VID, with a constraint on the materialized view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can come very close to what you want without a trigger.

You can use a check constraint for the first:

```
alter table Employee add constraint chk_vid_fid
    check (vid is not null or fid is null);
```

You can do the second using a unique constraint:

```
create unique index unq_Employee_vid on
    Employee(case when vid is null then -1 else id end);
```

This formulation assumes that `id` is non-negative, as most ids usually are.  If you do use the full range of integer values, then I would be explicit with a string:

```
create unique index unq_Employee_vid on
    Employee(case when vid is null then 'null vid' else cast(id as varchar2(255)) end);
```

This guarantees *at most* one row where `vid` is null, rather than *exactly* one row.  You cannot easily have a constraint that guarantees that exactly one row has a value, because empty tables do not match the condition -- and tables are empty when they are created.

Comment: `-1` is a valid value for `id` (declared `int`); an invalid value, perhaps `0.5`, is a better choice for this approach, since it is guaranteed not to conflict with valid inserts, no matter how unusual.

Comment: As you stated yourself, this solution does **not** implement the OP's requirement. I just posted one solution - using materialized views.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can enforce your requirement - to have **exactly** one row with `VID is NULL`. As I said in my Comment under your original question (and Gordon said as well in his accepted Answer), you cannot do this just with constraints. However, you can do it with a materialized view. Note that you must create the MV with `refresh fast on commit`, and that requires certain things for the materialized view log on the base table.

Also: If you try everything exactly as written, the constraint on the MV will fail (of course, because the base table will be empty, so there will be no row where `VID` is `NULL`). Add rows to the base table, of which exactly one has `NULL` for `VID`, then `commit` the transaction, and then execute the `alter table` command to add the constraint to the MV. From that point on, a transaction on the base table (consisting of one or more `insert`, `delete`, `update` or `merge` statements, followed by one `commit`) will go through if and only if it leaves exactly one row with `NULL` in the `VID` column.

One oddity to keep in mind: even though there is an `ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW` statement in Oracle SQL, to add a constraint on a MV we must use the `ALTER TABLE` statement (with the MV's name), not `ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

Note that I used the name `t_Employee` for the base table, as I already had a table `EMPLOYEE` and I don't want to mess with my existing objects.

```
create table t_Employee(
Id   int primary key,
Name varchar(15) not null,
VID  int,
FID  int
);

alter table t_Employee add constraint chk_vid_fid
    check (vid is not null or fid is null)
;

create materialized view log on t_Employee 
with rowid
(VID)
including new values
;

create materialized view mv_Employee
refresh fast on commit
as select count(*) ct
   from   t_Employee
   where  VID is null
;

alter table mv_Employee add constraint chk_vid_ct
    check (ct = 1)
;
```